# Why can setLayout() be called without specifying a class or object in Java?

Tags: java, swing, methods, constructor

This is the beginning of the MidiSynth class from the [Java Sound Demo](http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/sound/samples/JavaSoundDemo/). I was under the impression that methods in Java were always called from an object or a class. Where does the setLayout() method come from here?

```
public class MidiSynth extends JPanel implements ControlContext {
    // Fields omitted

    public MidiSynth() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.setLayout(new BoxLayout(p, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        EmptyBorder eb = new EmptyBorder(5,5,5,5);
        BevelBorder bb = new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED);
        CompoundBorder cb = new CompoundBorder(eb,bb);
        p.setBorder(new CompoundBorder(cb,eb));
        JPanel pp = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        pp.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10,20,10,5));
        pp.add(piano = new Piano());
        p.add(pp);
        p.add(controls = new Controls());
        p.add(new InstrumentsTable());

        add(p);
    }
```

Comment: Ok, you tell me from where `add(p)` comes from? if you answer this question, you get an answer

Comment: You are *not* calling it without an object. You are calling it on 'this' object, which is an instance of JPanel() by inheritance. And JPanel's constructor will be called before running anything on your child class's constructor.

Comment: @Eng: I was scratching my head wondering what you meant, til it dawned on me that you were referring to the implied "this".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MidiSynth extends JPanel`

So the `setLayout` call is actually invoking `this.setLayout`

Comment: Does myMethod(args) always mean this.myMethod(args) if a class or object isn't specified?

Comment: @parcaudex - Yes, there's always an implied `this` in front of every method or field reference (or the class name instead of `this` in case of static members).

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. I wasn't paying attention to the fact that a constructor can call methods of its superclass.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, `setLayout()` is defined in [java.awt.Container](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, because your class `MidiSynth` inherits `JPanel` that means you can deal with all JPanel's methods as you deal with local methods of `MidiSynth` class.